# meteor d3.js fails to display contextmenu

Tags: meteor, d3.js

I have d3.js force-driven graph with contextmenu (and many other elements) which I'd like to transfer the project to meteor. Contextmenu is draw by nodeMenu function which is presented below.

```
d3.selectAll("circle").on("contextmenu", function(d,i) {nodeMenu(d, i)} ); 

function nodeMenu(d,i) {
  d3.selectAll('.context-menu').data([1])
    .enter()
    .append('div')
    .attr('class', 'context-menu');

  d3.event.preventDefault();
  d3.selectAll('.context-menu')
    .html('<center> context menu </center>')
    .append('ul')
    .selectAll('li')
    .data([1,2,3,4]).enter()
    .append('li')
    .text(function(d) { return d });

    d3.select('.context-menu').style('display', 'block') 
      .style('left', (d3.event.pageX - 2) + 'px') 
      .style('top', (d3.event.pageY - 2) + 'px') 
      .style('display', 'block');
}
```

When I moved the code to meteor I copy the code to client/main.js:

```
Template.d3app.rendered = function () { 
  oryginal_d3_code_with_few_tiny_changes }
```

My template is very simple. In main.html I have:

```
<template name="d3app">
  <p> app</p>
  <div id="app"></div> 
</template>
```

Unfortunatelly it doesn't work. I got following error:

> d3.js?hash=aca575a…:824 Uncaught HierarchyRequestError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': Only one element on document allowed.

So the questions are:

1. What should I change in my code to get it work with meteor? (I have only problem with context menu all others elements and action from d3 works fine, I supposed I should add something more to my template ...)
2. In original code I use contextmenu to add/remove data which I later visualized. Is this approach reasonable or should I modified this and use some meteor feature to interact with user?
3. I am completely new to meteor so any comments/suggests are warmly welcome.

Edit: 
Based on (lack of) answers I assume it is impossible or very complicated so I guess possible workaround is: 
a) use d3 to determine where/what user click on (e.g. d3.selectAll("circle").on("click", createAndDisplayMenuUsingMeteor(d,i, mouseClickX, mouseClickY)) ) 
b) use meteor to generate and display proper menu in proper place. Based on d3.event.pageX I know where to put menu, using data from mongo (and node type from d3) I know what should be in the menu.

The a) part is obvious and is already done in the code presented above. I now the problem is how to display menu (context or on-click-menu, doesn't matter) in meteor. Any Idea?

Answer (score 0):

I will answer my question. My solution is:

1. in d3 I call meteor function:

   d3.selectAll("polygon").on("click", function (d,i) {
     Meteor.MyApp.nodeMenu(d,i, d3.event.x, d3.event.y); 
   });
2. in the function I have:

   nodeMenu: function(d,i,x,y) {
           var elem=document.getElementById("modNode");
           elem.style.position="absolute";
           elem.style.display = "block";
           //show menu in proper place
           elem.style.left=x+"px";
           elem.style.top=y+"px";
           // find node in mongo
           var theNode=Nodes.findOne({name:d.name } );
   },
3. In html file I have defined template with  which is invisible by default. After click  with menu became visible with proper data (taken from mongo).